# Can cyclotron/gyromagnetic resonance occur if the peak of an AC wave corresponds with the resonance frequency?

Tags: electromagnetism, frequency, resonance

So basically I'm curious if it's possible for cyclotron resonance to occur with a non-static, AC magnetic field if the frequency of it is equal to the cyclotron resonance frequency at the peak AC magnetic field strength.  I found some material on cyclotron autoresonance.  [This paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Leonid-Kalyakin/publication/314488479_Asymptotic_analysis_of_the_model_of_gyromagnetic_autoresonance/links/5b7a6e3f299bf1d5a716bd98/Asymptotic-analysis-of-the-model-of-gyromagnetic-autoresonance.pdf) talks about cyclotron autoresonance, particularly on page 4 (or page 5 counting from the page before the article starts), but I'm not entirely sure if this is what I'm describing.